# Need to determine if firewall is blocking an outbound connection

Tags: networking, firewall, sftp, nmap

I don't have direct control over the firewall. I'm trying to troubleshoot a connection to a SFTP site from a Unix machine. Pinging the host results in a timeout, and nmap is telling me the host may be down (although it is not). I suspect the outbound connection is being blocked by firewall settings - how can I confirm that this is indeed the issue?

Comment: nmap -Pn -p 22 $HOST ;

iptables -L -n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not much info, but here a guideline i would follow to debug this kind of issue if not in control of the firewall:

- Ping won't help, ICMP is a protocol that could be blocked as well
  somewhere/somehow along the path.
- Make a test using a different connection if applicable.
- Make a test connecting to other SSH/SFTP site.
- Eliminate protocol/configuration complexity and just try to telnet port 22 of remote host and see if cursor blinks or if you got ssh banner (in both cases connection is **not** blocked).
- Use **tcpdump -i your_interface port 22** and watch for [bidirectional traffic](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6447) and 3 way handshake to happen.